# "You are trying to merge an object and int64 columns" but both are same type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark

Weird problem, never faced it before. Make pandas frames out of spark to clean a specific column to prepare it for good join on its values.

```py
def clean(data):
    # manipulate input
    return data

x = spark_f1.toPandas()
x["clean_name"] = x["Name"].apply(clean)
x["clean_name"] = x["clean_name"].astype(str)

# do the same for y frame

for c in x.columns:
    if c in y.columns:
        print(c)

> get "clean_name"

x["clean_name"].dtype == y["clean_name"].dtype

> get True

joined = x.join(y, on="clean_name", how="left", lsuffix="_x", rsuffix="_y")

> You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns.
```

Anything I am missing?

Comment: Please provide some sample input data.

Comment: @Barmar - I think you misread the code.  The second one there is an `if` not a `for`.

Comment: Typo.  You have `lsuffux` instead of `lsuffix`, so it didn't rename the columns.

Comment: @TimRoberts Probably a copying error, otherwise they would have gotten an error due to the unknown keyword.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], including "do the same for y"

Comment: `join` uses the index of the right DataFrame, try: `x.join(y.set_index("clean_name"), on="clean_name", how="left", lsuffix="_x", rsuffix="_y")`

Answer (score 0):

Before this 'for' loop, try to add these codes as follows.

```
# Convert column names to lowercase for case-insensitive matching
x.columns = x.columns.str.lower()
y.columns = y.columns.str.lower()
```

If you want to compare column names between x and y, it's advisable to convert column names to a common format (e.g., lowercase) before the comparison to ensure case-insensitive matching, as column names are case-sensitive by default in pandas.

Meanwhile, add these codes after "y.columns = y.columns.str.lower()"as well to make sure the same data type.

```
# Convert the "clean_name" column to a string data type in both DataFrames
x["clean_name"] = x["clean_name"].astype(str)
y["clean_name"] = y["clean_name"].astype(str)
```